# Has anyone else experienced this build error in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Could someone please help me with this build issue?

I've unchecked and re-added the scenes in the build but whenever I click any of the buttons that are supposed to link me to the next scene that error pops up. So it recognised where the link is and what button is supposed to do to what. So I haven't got any code errors. As you can see everything is there in the right order in the build. I want the link between the builds to response. The build is successful and the code all works (even confirmed with the error).

I can't figure out what the issue is, even after re-importing all the assets or refreshing the scenes downloading all standard assets. I haven't changed where the scene files are saved to either. Thoughts?

I want the link between the builds to response. The build is successful and the code all works (even confirmed with the error).

[image]

Comment: What is the code you are using to navigate to scene 3?

Comment: It's always useful and valued if you post your used/relevant scripts when asking a question. It provides clarity and makes it easier to address the issue.

Comment: please add code and output as raw text instead of an image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is usually helpful if you could post the code in question, however looking at the error message, you are trying to load a scene with the **name** `'3'` instead of the number 3.

To fix it:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(3);
```

Edit: i saw the comment you deleted. You need to remove the `" "` around your 3.

Comment: It may just be that the console adds the quotation signs around the variable. To show that it is a variable. But if not, its of course a good thing for OP to check.

Comment: He posted his code in a comment, it had the quotation signs. However he removed the comment shortly after.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thank you so much guys